# Button in other cell: Xamarin.Forms

Tags: button, grid, xamarin.forms, cell

How to add button in other cell?
I tried to do that but is not working. Thanks for help. My cod:

```
var button = new Image { Source = "page.png"};
        button.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command((async sender =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new page());
            }))
        });

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 200 });

        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "00"}, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "01"}, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "02"}, 0, 2);

        grid.Children.Add(button, 1, 0); //this is not visible
        grid.Children.Add(button, 1, 1); //this is not visible
        grid.Children.Add(button, 1, 2);

        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "20"}, 2, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "21"}, 2, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "22"}, 2, 2);
```

Comment: You can't use the same instance of a control in multiple cells.  You need to create a new instance for each Cell you want it to appear in.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same instance of a control in multiple cells. You need to create a new instance for each Cell you want it to appear in.

```
var button1 = new Image { Source = "page.png"};
var button2 = new Image { Source = "page.png"};
var button3 = new Image { Source = "page.png"};

// add gesture recognizers to each instance

grid.Children.Add(button1, 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(button2, 1, 1);
grid.Children.Add(button3, 1, 2);
```